# Как создать лобби в библиотеке aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Как реализовать лобби на 2-4 игрока, в библиотеке aiogram

Answer (score 1):

Интересный вопрос
Есть такое классный метод aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state.State
Вот код

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Command
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.types import ParseMode
from aiogram.utils import executor

bot = Bot(token='TOKEN')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# Создаем состояние лобби
class Lobby(StatesGroup):
    players = State()  # Список игроков
    max_players = State()  # Максимальное количество игроков

# Обработчик команды /start
@dp.message_handler(Command("start"))
async def start_game(message: types.Message):
    # Запрашиваем количество игроков
    await message.answer("Сколько игроков будет играть?")
    # Устанавливаем состояние Lobby.players и переводим пользователя в него
    await Lobby.players.set()

# Обработчик текстового сообщения, который получает количество игроков
@dp.message_handler(state=Lobby.players)
async def set_max_players(message: types.Message, state: dict):
    try:
        max_players = int(message.text)
        if max_players >= 2 and max_players <= 4:
            # Устанавливаем максимальное количество игроков
            await state.update_data(max_players=max_players)
            # Сохраняем список игроков
            await message.answer("Кто будет играть? Введите имена через запятую.")
            # Переводим пользователя в состояние Lobby.players
            await Lobby.players.set()
        else:
            await message.answer("Количество игроков должно быть от 2 до 4.")
    except ValueError:
        await message.answer("Введите число.")

# Обработчик текстового сообщения, который получает список игроков
@dp.message_handler(state=Lobby.players)
async def set_players(message: types.Message, state: dict):
    try:
        players = message.text.split(',')
        # Удаляем пробелы у имен игроков
        players = [player.strip() for player in players]
        # Проверяем, что количество игроков соответствует максимальному
        if len(players) == state["max_players"]:
            # Сохраняем список игроков
            await state.update_data(players=players)
            # Отправляем сообщение со списком игроков
            await message.answer(f"Список игроков: {', '.join(players)}")
# Обработчик команды /play, который начинает игру
@dp.message_handler(Command("play"), state=Lobby.players)
async def play_game(message: types.Message, state: dict):
    players = state["players"]
    # Проверяем, что количество игроков соответствует максимальному
    if len(players) == state["max_players"]:
        # Начинаем игру
        await message.answer("Игра начинается!")
        # Сбрасываем состояние пользователя
        await state.finish()
    else:
        await message.answer("Количество игроков не соответствует максимальному.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Вот а можно еще чуть иначе все провернуть, более интересно

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Command
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.types import ParseMode
from aiogram.utils import executor

import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token="TOKEN_HERE")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

class Lobby(StatesGroup):
    players = State()
    players_names = State()

@dp.message_handler(Command("start"), state="*")
async def start_game(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Добро пожаловать в лобби! Сколько игроков будет участвовать?")
    await Lobby.players.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Lobby.players)
async def get_players(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data["player_count"] = int(message.text)
    await message.answer("Введите имена игроков, через запятую:")
    await Lobby.players_names.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Lobby.players_names)
async def add_player(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        if "players" not in data:
            data["players"] = []
        data["players"].extend([name.strip() for name in message.text.split(",")])
    if len(data["players"]) == data["player_count"]:
        await message.answer(f"Начинаем игру! Игроки: {', '.join(data['players'])}")
        await state.finish()
    else:
        await message.answer(f"Введите еще {data['player_count'] - len(data['players'])} имен(a).")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True
```

Тут можно кучу всего добавить еще, в общем фантазия тебе в помощь